# Pay Outstanding demand

Tags: income-tax, india

I got an outstanding demand for the AY 2009-10 under section1431a, i paid that now when I open the site it is showing another outstanding demand under section 220(2). I think this amount is the interest of that outstanding demand which was raised 5 years back.Am I right?
Now I need to pay CPC demand under section 220(2) and I am planning to pay this amount using Challan280 but Could you please tell me what will be the payment details mode from the following?
Income Tax ,Surcharge, Education Cess, Interest, Penalty, or others.

Is that will be Interest?

And once I pay this amount do i need to do anything like need to file any revise return(my friend was telling)? I don't have any idea on this.

Answer (score 1):

When did you get the notice under 143 1a? Generally it should be within a year of filing returns. See [here](http://www.incometaxindia.gov.in/Pages/acts/income-tax-act.aspx)

Is the interest demand under 220(2) for the same year? Generally the 143 1a would have calculated interest as well.

Please consult a Professional CA. You would need to pay this as "Interest" and file revised returns.